# Use of CSS in SQL multi Records

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

I want to give new touch to my site through CSS, but i dont know how to use different CSS styles into multiple SQL Outcome, Let me explain this from example....

Suppose

```
$sql = "SELECT id, text FROM tgrp437 WHERE active='1' and uid='".$ud."' LIMIT 20";

$items = mysql_query($sql);

echo mysql_error();

if(@mysql_num_rows($items)>0)

{

 while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($items))

 {
$gold=$item[1]

}}
```

So I want to display

all **20 rows** into different colors or CSS tags Like :

```
echo '1-<font color="red">'.$gold.'</font>';

echo '2-<font color="green">'.$gold.'</font>';

echo '3-<font color="blue">'.$gold.'</font>';

echo '4-<font color="purple">'.$gold.'</font>';
```

How can I Like this ??

Please help me !!

Thanks !!

Comment: you can apply same colur for even and another color for odd rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid using outdated functions. The `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated, and will soon be disappearing from newer versions of PHP. Instead, you should look into [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements.

Also, rather than the `font` tag, it'd be better to use `span` and define classes for the colours that you wish to use. You can easily update your code to use this as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, text FROM tgrp437 WHERE active='1' and uid='".$ud."' LIMIT 20";
$items = mysql_query($sql);
$colors = array('red', 'green', 'etc...');
$i = 0;
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($items))
{
    echo '<span class="'.$colors[$i].'">'.$item[1].'</span>';
    $i++;
}
```

As you can see, you create an array holding the numerous classes that you wish to use. **The length of the array must match the number of records that you're returning**, or you could just assign a colour randomly from the specified list as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, text FROM tgrp437 WHERE active='1' and uid='".$ud."' LIMIT 20";
$items = mysql_query($sql);
$colors = array('red', 'green', 'etc...');
$max_color = count($colors) - 1;
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($items))
{
    echo '<span class="'.$colors[rand(0, $max_color)].'">'.$item[1].'</span>';
}
```

You can then define your CSS classes as follows:

```
span.red { color: red; }
span.green { color: green; }
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank you so much bro !!

I have done that. But suppose if i want to set only 2 colors on random basis then how would I able to do that ??

Comment: Just specify two colors in the `$color` array of the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color model. You just need to write some function, that will return diffirent hue, depending on line number, and take constant saturation and value. Than convert it into RGB.

So you can generate series of different colors.